# hough circle opencv coordinates of circles' center

Tags: opencv, geometry

I am using [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) page to identify circles and their centers on my images. I know that top left hand corner is 0,0 point. But then i noticed that x and y coordinates returned for my circles' center are all positive. Why is that? shouldn't y coordinate be negative? I am talking about `circles[i][1]` values from the original code.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is correct.

In computer vision, usually, the y-axis is inverted.

OpenCV follows this coordinate system:

[image]

[Image from here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/11006/what-is-the-carttopolar-angle-direction-in-opencv/).